# PHP Traits naming convention?

Tags: php, zend-framework, naming-conventions, traits

What is the naming convention for using traits in a Zend Framework project?

`My_Form_Element_Traits` or `My_Form_Element_Trait`?

I am thinking plural as it's a collection of methods and properties, however on the other hand it *is* one trait.

I also thought that maybe there are different traits I want to use so maybe it should be `My_Form_Element_Traits_Preference`

What is the best practice hear to this new feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in what convention is used by [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/):
https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/bylaws/009-naming-conventions.md

And in my opinion, even when you use ZF1, you shouldn't follow this convention. I recommend you to use [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md)